# how to open different website with act_window openerp

Tags: odoo

I need to open website from the UI of OpenERP project, for example google.com.
It must be in **act_window** tag. How to pass parameters dynamicly in URL ,
for example  http://www.google.bg/?q=sun?

Answer (score 4):

Since you need it to be dynamic, you need to create a method and return an dictionary of `ir.actions.url`. Then just attach this method to a button. (Note: you may need to open a wizard with the button on it if you need to have the main button on the sidebar).

```
from openerp import models, api

class MyClass(models.Model):
    _name = "my_module.my_class"

    @api.multi
    def openURL(self):
        q = "sun"
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
            'url': "http://www.google.bg/?q=%s" % q,
            'target': 'new', # open in a new tab
        }
```

In your view XML:

```
<button name="openURL" string="Open URL" type="object">
```

the `name` attribute is the name of the method to call

Answer (score 3):

I do not know either it can possible with `act_window` or not.
but I'm sure that we can open url through `ir.actions.url` model.

I do not tried it. but the hint can guide you.

1) create action record with `ir.actions.url` model and url

2) create menuitem for the same action with `type='url'`

3) you need to create wizard to open particular url address. with

`'type': 'ir.actions.act_url'` and

`'url':"web address"` in return values.

hope, it could help you.

Comment: i need button or link in sidebar, are you have any idea

Comment: I am not sure for act window but you can create wizard (same as normal wizard view in sidebar) view.

Comment: It opens but it will concatenate with <localhost:1234>/<my_URL>... Any Solution for that ?